# ERROR: could not find driver after changing from mysql to mariadb

Tags: centos, php, mariadb

mysql was working fine but I wanted to give mariadb a try on a new server I have going. However I am having an issue where all my php websites seem to have issues communicating with mariadb. Webmin works for me, but I get this warning for mysql.

> Warning: The Perl module DBD::mysql is not installed on your system,
>   so Webmin will not be able to reliably access your MySQL database.
>   Click here to install it now.

One possible solution I keep finding is to try to install php-mysql, but I get the following error

```
~]# yum install php-mysql
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.sunet.se
 * extras: ftp.sunet.se
 * updates: ftp.sunet.se
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.3.3-23.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
Package mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 is obsoleted by MariaDB-shared-5.5.33a-1.i686 which is already installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
Package mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 is obsoleted by MariaDB-shared-5.5.33a-1.i686 which is already installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.66-2.el6_3.x86_64 (base)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.67-1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.66-2.el6_3.x86_64 (base)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.67-1.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Here is the full error for my php script which works with mysql but not mariadb

> ERROR: could not find driver Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   /var/www/html/index.php on line 137 Fatal error: Call to a
>   member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/html/classes/DB.class.php on line 75

5.5.33a-MariaDB MariaDB Server
Centos 6.4
The I can log in to mysql in terminal where it shows the mariadb version, I can also see and manage tables in webmin but none of my php scripts work, including wordpress.

Comment: Looks like that `php` module is compiled against `5.1` but you have `5.5` installed.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this tip on the MariaDB Knowledgebase. The title of the article, [How can I upgrade from MySQL to MariaDB?](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-can-i-upgrade-from-mysql-to-mariadb/#comment_419).

It's also covered here on in this articled, titled: [Install LEMP Server (Nginx With MariaDB And PHP) On CentOS 6](http://www.unixmen.com/install-lemp-nginx-with-mariadb-and-php-on-centos-6/).

Bottom line is that you need to make use of the 3rd party repository, REMI to resolve these dependencies.

```
$ rpm -ivh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
```

Follow the directions in the LEMP article for details on how to migrate from MySQL to MariaDB!